# Why is my request to web service timing out on 3G connection? iphone

Tags: iphone, web-services, connection, 3g

I make a request to the web service, but when I choose 3G connection, the didfailwitherror method is called and the error "The request timed out" is displayed. When the connection is wifi, I get the expected result.

I implemented correctly all the methods that can be triggered, but I don't know how to solve this problem. Could this happen, because the response is too big? I also increased the timeoutInterval, but no success.

This is the response:

[{"value" : "1 septembrie - 23 octombrie 2009 "}, {"value" : "1 septembrie - 30 septembrie 2009"}, {"value" : "17 noiembrie - 25 noiembrie 2009"}, {"value" : "7 decembrie - 16 decembrie 2009"}, {"value" : "22 februarie - 29 martie 2010"}, {"value" : "01 august - 31 august 2010"}, {"value" : "18 octombrie - 30 noiembrie 2010"}, {"value" : "14 februarie - 31 martie 2011"}, {"value" : "26 aprilie - 29 aprilie 2011"}, {"value" : "29 iunie - 20 iulie 2011"}, {"value" : "06 septembrie - 14 septembrie 2011"}, {"value" : "10 octombrie - 06 decembrie 2011"}, {"value" : "7 decembrie - 31 decembrie 2011"}, {"value" : "15 februarie - 30 martie 2012"}, {"value" : "5 aprilie - 9 mai 2012"}, {"value" : "05 noiembrie 2012"}, {"value" : "05 noiembrie - 22 noiembrie 2012"}, {"value" : "23 noiembrie - 06 decembrie 2012"}, {"value" : "03 decembrie - 28 decembrie 2012"}]

Here is the code:

```
  NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@api-v2.asmx", MainUrl]];

NSMutableURLRequest * request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                                        cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                    timeoutInterval:50.0];

NSString * parameters = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[self XmlRequest]];
NSLog(@"Request=%@", parameters);
NSString * msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [parameters length]];

[request addValue:@"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request addValue:@"http://tempuri.org/GetIndexLinkedTable" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
[request addValue:msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody:[parameters dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


NSURLConnection * connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:YES];

if (connection){
    self.responseData = [NSMutableData data];
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the connection should stay alive. `NSURLConnection` is a pretty smart class as far as network data transfer is concerned. However, there are a few things you can try. There is a property of `NSURLRequest` that sets a timeout interval. It can be set as follows

```
request.timeoutInterval = 60.0
```

Try this to see if it helps, as I have heard there are/were some issues with using it in the constructor. Your data is probably not big enough to warrant a timeout though, so also check your server settings to make sure it is able to accept requests, and has a decent timeout interval set as well.